# Syslog support under Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, syslog

Does Tomcat 7 `java.util.logging` support sending logs to a remote syslog server?

It looks like `log4j` supports this:

`log4j.appender.SYSLOG = org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender`

However, we are currently using `RemoteIpValve` so I'm not sure that will work under log4j.

**server.xml**

```
 <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" 
    internalProxies="x.x.x.x" />

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
    directory="${LOG_DIR}/tomcat" prefix="access" suffix=".log" 
    pattern="combined" renameOnRotate="true" requestAttributesEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: Have you read [Use log4j in Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j)?

Comment: There's no mention of RemoteIpValve in the section